# React document.getElementById() returns a disconnected element, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am writing an hook that receives an HTMLElement as argument. I would like to make it so that it can accept even just an `id` and then find the element on its own.

I run `document.getElementById()` inside an `useEffect` in the hook.
In this way the DOM is queried only after the component calling the hook has been rendered in the actual DOM.
And I save the element straight away in react ref.

If I run my app and navigate to render the component with the hook, everything works perfectly. But if I continue to navigate so that the component is unmounted and then I navigate back to mount it again, the app crashes.

After a little digging I found the problem to be that, while the element returned by `document.getElementById` is the same in both cases (because the id is the same), [`Node.isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) returns `true` in the first case and `false` when the crash occurs.

Anyone knows what may cause this difference?
Note that after the first successful mount, the component is unmounted and mounted brand new.

Ps: it would be great if you could provide a theoretical answer rather than requiring a minimal reproducible example, as at the moment I don't have access to my laptop, and yet I can't stop obsessing myself with this problem.

Comment: React is under no obligation to expose to you a consistent DOM. It can very easily remove a node from the DOM and insert a *new* node with that id and you have a stale reference to the old one, which is why you're supposed to clean that up with the function you return from `useEffect`.

Comment: @JaredSmith so then there would be two elements with the same id around? For cleaning up you mean reassign the ref to `null` or what?

Comment: yes. *Normally* the old detached one would just get garbage collected, but you're holding a reference to it, so.... and yes to your second question.

Comment: And the reference is not trashed automatically when the component is unmounted?

Comment: You might find [this helpful](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780)

Comment: I found it helpful, however I am not sure this will solve my problem as the approach used is to get the element from the jsx, not from an id. I will check whether the problem originated from the ref holding an old detached element or from the element returned by `getElementById`. I'll report back.

Comment: @JaredSmith at the second mount (when the crash occurs) `getElementById` wasn't even called. The hook was magically receiving an element rather than an id. I found that I was messing up with one state, by modifying it without calling setState and fixing this also fixed the argument received by the hook. Once the hook received the id tha was actually passed to it, rather than an element coming out of nowhere, the app just worked fine. So my bad. Thank you anyway for all the useful informations!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed!